# facebook integration in my blackerry app

Tags: blackberry

I have implemented a blackberry application that connects to Facebook and posts a status on the Facebook wall. The problem is that the application every time asks for login/password when it is going to post a status.

Is there a way to overcome this issue and keep the application logged on ?

Comment: Hi I am also trying to integrate facebook with my blackberry app. But i am unable to open the Login screen. Can u please post some sample code plzz....